# uWSGI command not found

Tags: django, proxy, uwsgi

## Background:

I am in the process of deploying a Django site and from my understanding and research, I needed to get a web server, a WSGI protocol interface to actually run said python code and 'communicate' with it, and lastly a reverse proxy server to tie the two together and pass HTTP requests through the pipeline to Django. (By virtue of my install method, `mod_wsgi` is not an option thanks to EasyApache4 and cPanel so I cannot use the `mod_wsgi` sockets method)

## My problem:

I have organized an apache 2 hosting server and managed to install `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_uWSGI` using the EasyApache4 auto installer. From what I understand, now I need to set up the proxy system to relay HTTP requests through `mod_proxy_uWSGI` which doubles up and also runs my Django site, however, I cannot access or configure `mod_proxy_uWSGI`. When I try using the following style command (sorry, I don't want my server URLs floating around the internet):

```
 uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file test.py
```

I get an error message:

```
bash: uwsgi: command not found
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You actually need to install uwsgi itself using either `pip install` or `apt-get`

Comment: oh wow. I feel like an idiot...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to a comment by [@dirkgroten]. To install UWSGI :
`pip install uwsgi`

Answer (score 4):

After running `pip install uwsgi`, it's possible that `uwsgi` was installed someplace not on your `PATH`. IE, in my case, it got installed to:

```
/usr/local/opt/python-3.8.6/bin/uwsgi
```

I was able to fix this by adding a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/python-3.8.6/bin/uwsgi /usr/bin/uwsgi
```

(This may be a terrible idea. It may be a much better idea to use a `venv`, but I'm following a tutorial that specifically told me to avoid using a `venv`.)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @ArtOfWarfare's answer, you can check where pip is installing your packages using this command.

```
▶ pip show uwsgi
Name: uWSGI
Version: 2.0.21
Summary: The uWSGI server
Home-page: https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Author: Unbit
Author-email: info@unbit.it
License: GPLv2+
Location: /Users/username/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

In my case, it is `/Users/username/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages`. So the uwsgi binary will be present in `/Users/username/Library/Python/3.9/bin/`. Add this location to PATH and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using Docker, I found the binary to be located in:

```
/home/webappuser/.local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

do not install from apt-get rather install pip install

also symlink if needed